# How to fasten nested for-loop R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two datasets, and one of them is very big. I'm trying to run the following loop to create a treatment column, `treatment`, in the dataset `a`. However, it is way too slow. I looked for a way to fasten for-loops like vectorization or defining conditions outside the loops however I'm having a hard time applying those methods since I have two datasets I'm conditioning on.

Here is my code:

```
reform_loop <- function(a, b){
  for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    
    for(j in 1:nrow(b)){
      if(!is.na(a[i,"treatment"])){break}
      

      a[i,"treatment"] <- case_when(a[i,"country_code"] == b[j, "country_code"] &
                            a[i,"birth_year"] >= b[j,"cohort"] &
                            a[i,"birth_year"]<= b[j,"upper_cutoff"] ~ 1,
                          
                          a[i,"country_code"] == b[j, "country_code"] &
                            a[i,"birth_year"] < b[j,"cohort"]&
                            a[i,"birth_year"]>= b[j,"lower_cutoff"] ~ 0)
      
    }
  }
  return(a)
}

a <- reform_loop(a, b)
```

You can find a sample dataset below. Dataset `a` is an individual dataset with birth year informations and dataset `b` is country-level data with some country reform information. `treatment` is 1 if the`birth_year` is between the `cohort` and `upper_cutoff` and 0 if between `cohort` and `lower_cutoff` in a specific country which means `country_code` variables should also be matched. And anything else should be NA.

```
#individual level data, birth years
a <- data.frame (country_code = c(2,2,2,10,10,10,10,8), 
                               birth_year = c(1920,1930,1940,1970,1980,1990, 2000, 1910))
#country level reform info with affected cohorts
b <- data.frame(country_code = c(2,10,10,11),
                      lower_cutoff = c(1928, 1975, 1907, 1934),
                      upper_cutoff = c(1948, 1995, 1927, 1948),
                      cohort = c(1938, 1985, 1917, 1942))
```

The following is the result I want to get:

```
treatment <- c(NA, 0, 1, NA, 0, 1, NA, NA)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot merge these two datasets since most of the countries in my dataset have more than one reform.

Any ideas on how can I fasten this code? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `Error in nrow(reforms) : object 'reforms' not found`. And what is your expected output?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change the data frame name and add the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a range-based non-equi join. As such, this can be done with `data.table` or `fuzzyjoin` or `sqldf`.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
setDT(b)
b[, treatment := 1L]
a[b, treatment := i.treatment, on = .(country_code, birth_year >= lower_cutoff, birth_year <= upper_cutoff)]
a[is.na(treatment), treatment := 0L]
a
#    country_code birth_year treatment
#           <num>      <num>     <int>
# 1:            2       1920         0
# 2:            2       1930         1
# 3:            2       1940         1
# 4:           10       1970         0
# 5:           10       1980         1
# 6:           10       1990         1
# 7:           10       2000         0
# 8:            8       1910         0
```

### sqldf

```r
out <- sqldf::sqldf("select a.*, b.treatment from a left join b on a.country_code=b.country_code and a.birth_year between b.lower_cutoff and b.upper_cutoff")
out$treatment[is.na(out$treatment)] <- 0L
out
#   country_code birth_year treatment
# 1            2       1920         0
# 2            2       1930         1
# 3            2       1940         1
# 4           10       1970         0
# 5           10       1980         1
# 6           10       1990         1
# 7           10       2000         0
# 8            8       1910         0
```

### fuzzyjoin

```r
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(a, b, by = c("country_code" = "country_code", "birth_year" = "lower_cutoff", "birth_year" = "upper_cutoff"), match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
#   country_code.x birth_year country_code.y lower_cutoff upper_cutoff cohort treatment
# 1              2       1920             NA           NA           NA     NA        NA
# 2              2       1930              2         1928         1948   1938         1
# 3              2       1940              2         1928         1948   1938         1
# 4             10       1970             NA           NA           NA     NA        NA
# 5             10       1980             10         1975         1995   1985         1
# 6             10       1990             10         1975         1995   1985         1
# 7             10       2000             NA           NA           NA     NA        NA
# 8              8       1910             NA           NA           NA     NA        NA
```

and then you need to clean up the extra columns (and fill `0` for `NA`).

Comment: Thank you so much! First version of my question was poorly written, I actually had two different conditions, but after some modifications, the code successfully ran for all. However, in my original data set, I need more conditions, so I added the following code `a[b, treatment := i.argentina, on = .(ison, region_ison == 32002, birth_year >= pivotal_lower, birth_year < pivotal_upper)]` but I got the following error "Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE):argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[2]='32002'" Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I have nan values in the region column can it be the reason?

Comment: Don't put literals/constants in the `on=` component: if you want to omit `32002`, I suggest you filter it out of either or both datasets.

Comment: I actually want to adjust the treatment variable if the region code is 32002, not just omit it. But I guess I have to find another way for it.